# Import a Java Project as dependency into a Android project using Android Studio

Tags: android, maven, import, android-studio, project

I have a java project (built with maven) on CloudForge and I'm trying to use it as a dependency into a android project in Android Studio. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to include the project as a source module and include it in a Gradle-based project, which is how I interpret your question, then it's either impossible or it's very tricky, depending on what your threshold for the definition of "impossible" is.

Android Studio doesn't support projects with mixed build systems. It's intended that all projects will be Gradle-based, and it only gives you UI to create projects using Gradle. If you happen to have a project built with the IntelliJ builder or Maven that you got somewhere else, you can generally open it in Android Studio, though it may not work as well there as you like. But in all cases, the entire project is built with the same build system.

What makes me say it's not impossible is that in your Gradle build script, you could perhaps define a task that could call out to Maven to build the subproject, which could sort of work, though it's not going to get it dependencies right and may not rebuild the main project if the subproject changes.

Alternately, you could build the Maven-based module outside of Android Studio, compile it to a JAR, and include the JAR in your Android Studio project in the normal way.

Comment: Thanks my friend, you've made good points and made me think a lot about it! Though that's the first time I use Android Studio and I'm not very familiar with Gradle yet! This is just a matter of time! Thanks again!